# Django - Admin/Add running model.clean even though fields are missing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-validation

Ok, so I have a model like this:

```
class Airplane(models.Model):
    tail = models.ForeignKey(Tails)
    wheel = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    window = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.tail and self.wheel and self.window:
            raise ValidationError("Can't have all three, choose tail and one more")
```

Now if I go to add a new Airplane record using Django admin.  If I leave both fields blank and save I get this Django error pointing to the line `if self.tail and self.wheel`.

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/MyProject/airplane/add/

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://44.101.44.172:8001/admin/MyProject/airplane/add/
Django Version:     1.2.5
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __get__, line 299
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.0
```

Shouldn't Django be checking that the required fields are filled in before running clean?  In any case, what's the best way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as a workaround I ended up defining a [custom form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) with [my validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) in admin.py for this model.

I still don't understand why model.clean gets called before Django has determined that the required fields have been filled in.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Your tails field does not accept null values.  You will need to add `null=True` to it to make it work.

Comment: Well, no, the whole point is that I want tail to be required.

Comment: So I don't understand your validation.  If tail is required and tail+wheel is not a possible option, how can you have a wheel?  It will always be False.

Comment: It's a toy example to highlight the problem behaviour but to be clearer I updated the example to make it more realistic.

Comment: After you changed your example code, your code works perfectly as is. check it out.  If you don't specify a `tail`, it will shout for a tail.  If you specify all three, it will shout for all three.  You can (/should) change your if to `id self.wheel and self.window`, since `self.tail` is always true.

Comment: (Although the message should be "choose tail and **at most**" one more")